# Error connecting to a site over SSL

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

Good morning,

I'm trying to connect to a site using SSL and always receive the same exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message). I create a truststore with the site certificates and load them in runtime. This is the code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class SSLTest {

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug" , "ssl");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","123456");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Projectos\\GapM\\WebServiceTes\\src\\truststore.jks");

    URL url = new URL("https://www.segurnet.pt");
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());

    conn.disconnect();
}

private static class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

}

}
```

This is what i get:

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\Projectos\GapM\WebServiceTest\src\truststore.jks
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=luis gomes, OU=dti, O=acoreana, L=lisboa, ST=Unknown, C=pt
  Issuer:  CN=luis gomes, OU=dti, O=acoreana, L=lisboa, ST=Unknown, C=pt
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x181b641e
  Valid from Thu Mar 22 14:42:39 GMT 2012 until Thu Mar 29 15:42:39 BST 2012

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=www.segurnet.pt, OU=Web Server, OU=Associacao Portuguesa de Seguradores, OU=Corporate, OU=CERTIPOR - RA, O=MULTICERT-CA, C=PT
  Issuer:  CN=MULTICERT-CA 02, O=MULTICERT-CA, C=pt
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x426e98cd
  Valid from Fri Mar 16 14:54:03 GMT 2012 until Mon Apr 16 15:45:18 BST 2012

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1a5
  Valid from Thu Aug 13 01:29:00 BST 1998 until Tue Aug 14 00:59:00 BST 2018

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=MULTICERT-CA 02, O=MULTICERT-CA, C=pt
  Issuer:  CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x7273ce5
  Valid from Wed Jun 03 14:50:37 BST 2009 until Wed Oct 02 14:49:20 BST 2013

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1332495399 bytes = { 155, 93, 98, 157, 254, 204, 71, 133, 69, 221, 204, 14, 28, 124, 97, 184, 91, 139, 73, 188, 199, 75, 93, 224, 243, 135, 185, 67 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: www.segurnet.pt]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 173
main, READ: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, unexpected_message
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
```

Any help is apreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Luis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you need to force it to use SSLv3.

This fails:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.segurnet.pt:443
```

Whereas this works:

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect www.segurnet.pt:443
```

If possible, a better solution is to get the remote end to configure their site correctly. What they currently have is not very secure.

Comment: thanks @TonyM i was triyng to  System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3"); and get the same error... But try this  System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,SSLv2Hello"); and works.